# What does <C-O> mean?

Tags: vim, notation

I was reading the a [vim tips page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Best_Vim_Tips) and stumbled across `<C-O>`. How do I enter that on my keyboard? (I'm on a mac)

Answer (score 4):

In Vim (and Emacs) documentation, `C-` and `M-` stand for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>) respectively. So `C-O` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In documentation `C-` refers to the Control key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on a PC, or the Command key <kbd>⌘</kbd> on a Mac. It is pressed and held while the key after the `C-` is pressed, in your case <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: Most terminal applications inherited from the greater Unix-like world use the Control key on the Mac as well, not the Command key. This includes Vim. MacVim (the thirdparty build that provides a gui and is generally more up to date than the Vim that Apple provides built-in), does *add* some shortcuts that use the Command key, but it does not change standard Vim commands from Control to Command.

Comment: Vim actually has specific syntax for the Command key: `<D-...>`. This isn't MacVim specific, I've verified its presence in `:help key-notation` in Vim on Cygwin and native Windows.

Comment: @8bittree - The Macs I've worked with didn't have a Control key and needed to use the Command key instead. Maybe the latest Macs have both, in which case thanks for the information.

Comment: Well now I'm curious what Macs you've been using that didn't have Control keys. Apple's keyboards seem to have consistently had Control keys for at least a couple decades.

Comment: @8bittree - I've never used them in earnest, but only ever dabbled, so I have no real recollection of what models. It is certainly some time since I did so, possibly predating OS-X.